Installed the Videowise tracking pixel on my Shopify but its not firing
Installed the Videowise tracking pixel on Shopify store. When I checked the developer Network tab, I don't see it firing the pixel.

The Videowise Shoppable Video app extension is enabled.
Copied the tracking pixel from the videowise platform through the Custom Tracking Pixel code into our custom pixel container.
Cleared Cache and tried checking to see if the tag fired again.


Check to have the lates pixel code here and that Custom pixel is saved and connected.
Notice that tracking pixel is fired only on checkout_completed event, so you have to complete an order for the pixel to appear on Network. Refreshing the checkout_complete/thank_you page won't make the pixel run again since Shopify won't run the event on refresh.
For debugging, use the Test button for Videowise custom pixel in Customer events to see what's happening with the pixel in real-time while going through the order flow.
